# How can I plumb this bathroom configuration?

Tags: plumbing

Just wondering best way to run this bathroom configuration with venting. This bathroom will be in my basement.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: You need to show the length of **each** run for anyone to advise you on acceptable venting strategy.

Comment: Updated diagram with distance of runs. Thank you for your advice